# Using Javascript mailto and getting errors when url is >600 characters

Tags: javascript

My method for sending an email works pretty much like this,

```
function sendMail() 
{     
  var link = "mailto:me@example.com"              
  + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"              
  + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")              
  + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value);      

  window.location.href = link; 
}
```

I'm using alert(link.length) and anytime it goes over about 620 characters, the IE tab 'crashes', it gives the "This tab has been recovered" message, but does not actually recover very well at all.

What's up with that?

Comment: and I've tried using window.open to fire off the email instead of window.location.href and I get the same result

Comment: You probably know this, but for the sake of posterity: you can't rely on anything beyond the "To:" address being passed successfully to the mail user agent (or, if it's passed to it, of it being understood).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a limit [according to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#6).  I can't test the following as I only have access to a Mac at the moment, but have you tried this:

```
function sendMail() 
{     
    var mailForm = document.createElement('form');
    mailForm.id = 'mailForm';
    mailForm.action = 'mailto:user@mailinator.com';
    mailForm.method = 'get';

    var cc = document.createElement('input');
    cc.name = 'cc';
    cc.type = 'hidden';
    cc.value = 'ccUser@mailinator.com';

    var subject = document.createElement('input');
    subject.name = 'subject';
    subject.type = 'hidden';
    subject.value = escape("This is my subject");

    var msgBody = document.createElement('input');
    msgBody.name = 'body';
    msgBody.type = 'hidden';
    msgBody.value = escape(document.getElementById('myText').value);

    mailForm.appendChild(cc);
    mailForm.appendChild(subject);
    mailForm.appendChild(msgBody);
    document.body.appendChild(mailForm);
    document.forms['mailForm'].submit();
}
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv4gK/1/)

Comment: very interesting find with that link, I was unable to get anything from googling.  I'll test out the form idea.

Comment: still got the error. slight difference in that there was a warning message about an email getting ready to be sent out.. but still crashes the same.